# remove object in array based on object property with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have array of objects that can be removed with another array of objects i.e

```json
data = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 3},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "c", qty: 1}
]
```

and i want to splice the array where the ids  are same with the bonusFromId

```json
temp = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "b", qty: 1}
]
```

the value that i expect is

```json
[ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1}
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1}
  {"id": 3, name: "c", qty: 1}
]
```

i tried with this but it didnt worked

```js
 data.forEach(x => {
  let index = temp.filter(y => x.bonusFromId == y.id).map((item) => { return item.id}).indexOf(x.id)
  arr.splice(index, 1)
 })
```

Comment: Im confused how its possible to expect all names with  name: "a"

Comment: my bad,
imma edit the question

Comment: what happened to the `{"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 3},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 1},`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 3},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "c", qty: 1}
]

const temp = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "b", qty: 1}
]

temp.forEach(t=>{
  let find = data.find(e => e.bonusFromId == t.id)
  // find t.id in data.bonusFromId
  let index = data.indexOf(find);
  // get index of item in array data
  data.splice(index, 1);
  // splice it
  console.log(index)
})
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
min-height: 100%}
```

Or as stated in comment:

```js
const data = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 3},
  {"id": 2, name: "b", qty: 1, bonusFromId: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "c", qty: 1}
]

const temp = [ 
  {"id": 1, name: "a", qty: 1},
  {"id": 3, name: "b", qty: 1}
]

temp.forEach(t=>{
  let find = data.findIndex(e => e.bonusFromId == t.id)
  find >= 0 ? data.splice(find, 1) : null
  console.log(find)
})
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
min-height: 100%}
```

Comment: `let find = data.find(...); let index = data.indexOf(...)` is an anti-pattern. [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is used exactly for this purpose. Note, also be careful to check value of `index` before `splice`. `let index = data.findIndex(e => e.bonusFormId == t.id); if (index >= 0) data.splice(index, 1)`.